# Halacha and danger to life

Tags: halacha-theory, science, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, safek, health-safety-shmira

Suppose there is an halachically prescribed, commonly-practiced action, which has been demonstrated scientifically to lead to death of the action's object and/or subject with a certain low probability (assume that this probability cannot be further reduced).

What does the probability have to be for us to stop performing that action?

Is the probability even relevant?

Does the answer depend on whether the action is d'Rabanan, halacha l'Moshe mi'Sinaj, or d'Oraita?

P.S.: This is not an "anti-" or "pro-something" question. This is a sincere attempt to better understand the halachic process. Please abstain from assigning a specific mitzvah to the question, as there isn't one. Thanks.

Comment: If the action is, as you describe, "prescribed", why would you think we wouldn't do it?

Comment: @Daniel, Pikuach Nefesh.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Can pikuach nefesh apply for the typical case of a mitzvah? In other words, could there even *be* a mitzvah which would never be done because of pikuach nefesh? Why would such a mitzvah exist in the first place?

Comment: @Daniel, I think that (plus cases that aren't a Mitzva, per se) is what this question is asking.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I take the question to be assuming that such a mitzvah could exist. That seems unintuitive to me, so I'm asking how the OP came to that conclusion. sds, would you like to weigh in?

Comment: @Daniel: the circumstances change: things which were safe before might not be safe these days. So, the chazal might have established a mitzvah which is now dangerous.

Comment: Actual mitzva de-oraita this could apply to: fighting in a milchemet mitzva.

Comment: @Isaac that is very likely a unique case with its own rules.

Comment: Another _mitzva d'Oray'sa_ this could apply to: _mila_ (just the cutting).

Comment: Also fasting on yom kippur.

Comment: Heck, if someone did a scientific study on almost any _mitzva_, this could apply. There must be *some* low probability of dying from blowing _shofar_, after all, or from flapping at a bird to take her chicks. cc @Daniel

Comment: Part of this question is covered by the concept of והאידנא דדשו בה רבים, שומר פתאים ה- "in a situation where the masses tread, Hashem protects the simple people". A nice article covering this topic can be found in Techumim, vol. 24. Other articles on the subject שומר פתאים of can easily be found online.

Answer (score 2):

(For torah mitzvot)

one. the mitzva that all males must leave their homes and go to Jerusalem 3 times a year (during the first temple era) leaving all towns and borders undefended seems to be in this category.

from a military perspective this is reckless and suicidal (long term high probability of danger) and would leaving them vulnerable to being encircled and easily defeated. Turns out that no foreign nation ever came up to take the land of the Jews during their festivals prior to the destruction of Jerusalem 400+ years later.

two. Likewise, the laws of shmita and yovel where every single plot of land in the entire country be left unworked simultaneously for 2+years (in yovel) seems to be dangerous practice and could lead to a famine.

conclusion: if the mitzva is dangerous and there's no other way to do it, and no built in exemption to the mitzva  then the danger is not a deciding factor and you must do it.

Comment: I find your assertion that all cases of Pikuach Nefesh exempting one from a Mitzva to be individual built-in exceptions to be unsupported and unlikely.

Comment: I'm not addressing the question whether pikuach nefesh is a stand alone exemption or a built in exemption. the point here is that if a mitzva has no way out like the two examples above (which are not like bris mila which has an exemption) then you must do it even if its dangerous.

Comment: So you are saying that all cases of Pikuach Nefesh exempting one from a Mitzva are individual built-in exceptions...

Comment: not addressing the topic of whether pikuach nefesh is built in or not

Comment: I guess I was thrown off by your usage of the term "built in". IAE that wasn't primarily what I was skeptical of. I suppose now that you are saying that all cases of Pikuach Nefesh exempting one from a Mitzva are individual exceptions

Comment: i'm not talking about pikuach nefesh. thats a separate category. even the aliya l'regel and the shmita is exempt in a case of clear pikuach nefesh. i'm just showing that there are some mitzvot which are inherently dangerous to some extent and still the torah does not exempt

Comment: youre doing another thing though: you are extrapolating to all of torah from your two examples.

Comment: two examples is not enough?

Comment: Definitely not! Especially when both have [explicit promises](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0234.htm#24) in [the pasuk](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0325.htm#21) guaranteeing the Jews' safety. [כל שני כתובים הבאים כאחד אין מלמדין](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=34b&format=pdf)

Comment: it does nevertheless illustrate the principle that God is in charge and just do what you're supposed to do http://www.torah.org/learning/ravfrand/5760/kisisa.html  this was also the mistake of many jews fifty years ago who worked on shabbat because they thought their livelihood would not come otherwise and they would starve. The few who kept shabbat in those tough times, came out ahead and many of their children became leaders of the generation such as Rav Mendel Weinbach, zt'l

Comment: If your answer is "God is in charge and just do what you are supposed to", then how do you explain the principle of Pikuach Nefesh? How do you know those who didn't work on Shabbat didn't survive because of those who did and had money to contribute to communal organizations?

Comment: yes, that's what i'm saying. open up a separate question as to what is pikuach nefesh. likewise for those who worked on shabbat and how they survived.

Comment: I would open the first question, but then I'd have to close it as a dupe of this. This question is about at what point danger to life exempts one from performing a positive commandment. You don't really answer that.